# Issue plotting PDE solution with manipulate

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I am trying to plot the solution to the following PDE with the help of mathematica, however, when trying to employ manipulate to animate the behavior, I find that if I try this:

```
sol = DSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - x*D[u[t, x], x] == 0, u[0, x] == 1/((x^2) + 1)}, u[t, x], {t, x}]

Manipulate[Plot3D[u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 1], {t,0.001, 10}]
```

I get just an empty graph.

On the other hand, If I try this:

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, n}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 1], {n,0.001, 10}]
```

I do get a plot of the solution, but when I move the slider the image becomes distorted and does not update fluidly.

[image: Solution]

Is this some sort of a problem with how my machine is rendering this plot, or do I need to implement a solution within the code?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the automatic switching between when a control (e.g. slider) is actively being moved and when it has been releeased with [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html).

Better rendering takes more time, so it is up to the programmer to balance quality and speed, if the `Automatic` setting is unsatisfactory.  See also [`PerformanceGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html).

```
sol = DSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - x*D[u[t, x], x] == 0, 
   u[0, x] == 1/((x^2) + 1)}, u, {t, x}]

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, n}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 1, 
  MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[1, Automatic], 
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[15, 25], 
  Mesh -> ControlActive[None, Automatic]], {n, 0.001, 10}]
```

To fully understand how [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) works, read the four tutorials, the introductions and advanced ones, on [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) and `Manipulate` linked at the top of the documentation page of `Manipulate`.

The first try of the OP does not work because the instances of `t` in the `Manipulate` are localized in a `DynamicModule` created by `Manipulate`, while the `t` in `sol` is in the `` "Global`" `` context.  That problem can be avoided by having `DSolve` return a replacement rule in terms of a function, as I did above.